# Check if the user input is in my array

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I want to check if the user input is in my array. If it's not it shall write "Invalid input". The line reading already works. I just want to check this. But like I did it, it doesn't work. I heard that I shall use a for loop. But how?

```
[...]
char[] menuChars = { 'e', 'E', 'l', 'L', 'k', 'K', 't', 'T', 's', 'S', 'b', 'B' };

if (userKeyPress == !menuChars)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Please insert a valid char: ");
        }
Console.ReadLine()
[...]
```

Comment: `if(!menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress))`?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes. If, for some reason, you do not want to use Linq, given that the `menuChars` is a one-dimensional zero-indexed array, you will have to do either `if (Array.IndexOf(menuChars, userKeyPress) == -1)` or `if (!((ICollection<char>)menuChars).Contains(userKeyPress))`. Those are the .NET 2.0 ways.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Hmm, I see..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd rather *change* the collection type from array to `HashSet<Char>`:

```
  HashSet<Char> menuChars = new HashSet<Char>() {
    'e', 'E', 'l', 'L', 'k', 'K', 't', 'T', 's', 'S', 'b', 'B'
  };

  ...

  Char userKeyPress;

  // and condition check from "if" to "do..while" 
  // in order to repeat asking user until valid character has been provided
  do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert a valid char: ");
    // Or this:
    // userKeyPress = Console.Read();
    userKeyPress = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
  }
  while (!menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress));
```

Comment: When I paste this in my code "Console.ReadLine()" is red underlined and it doesn't work. What part of code can I send you to help you understanding my code?

Comment: @user5462581: depending on what do you mean by "insert a valid char" it could be either `Console.Read();` or `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`; I'm sorry for typo.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
using System.Linq;
...
if (!menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress))
...
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. And how can I repeat the line "Input valid char" until the user typed a valid one?

Comment: Glad to hear. I believe Dmitry Bychenko's answer show how to repeat the check.

Answer (score 1):

You can try lik ethis:

```
if(menuChars.Contains(userKeyPress))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
```

or like this:

```
if(Array.IndexOf(menuChars, userKeyPress) > -1)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
}
```